# Java - remove first occurence of char after selected string

Tags: java

In String text in Java, how can I remove all first occurences of a char after a given String? For example:

```
String s = "Aaaaa bbb cc dd dddd cc ttt d";
```

Remove first 'd' after 'cc' in the whole string.

Expected result:

```
String s = "Aaaaa bbb cc d dddd cc ttt ";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Java [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method. It lets you supply a regular expression that matches the term you would like to replace, and then provide a replacement string.

In this case, you're trying to match a `d` following the string `cc`, and remove it (replace it with a blank string).

The regular expression `"(cc.*?)d"` will match the first `d` anywhere after a `cc`, and then, because of the [*reluctant quantifier*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `*?`, won't match subsequent instances of `d`.

You can use the [*capturing group*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg) (`(...)`) to take note of what preceded the `d`, and then reference that in your replacement string.

So the solution becomes `string.replaceAll("(cc.*?)d", "$1")`, where `$1` is a reference to the text captured in the group.

Answer (score 2):

If you want simplicity without regex:

```
int ddIndex = s.indexOf("dd");
if (ddIndex != -1) {
 int cIndex = s.indexOf('c', ddIndex);
 if (cIndex != -1) {
   s = new StringBuilder(s).deleteCharAt(cIndex).toString();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 String s = "Aaaaa bbb cc dd dddd cc ttt d";
int x=  s.indexOf("cc")+1;
    for(int i=x;i<s.length();i++)
   {
     if(s.charAt(i)=='d')
     {s.replace(s.charAt(i),'');break;}
      }
```